# afterAction and returning method in yii2?

Tags: php, yii2

i have controller in common folder that have method test

```
  public function actionTest() {
    $s = "sdfs";
    return $s;
}
```

And have afterAction for this action like:

```
   public function afterAction($action) {
    if ($action->id == "test") { 
       echo 'here afterActioin';
     }
   }
```

and i call the test action from another controller :

```
public function actionTest3() {
  echo Yii::$app->runAction('travia/test');
 }
```

the problem is when i call the test3 in browser nothing display but if i comment the afterAction the method will return .
where is the problem what's the behaviour of the afterAction that doen't let my action to return something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yii2 docs

> This method is invoked right after an action is executed. The method
>   will trigger the EVENT_AFTER_ACTION event. The return value of the
>   method will be used as the action return value. If you override this
>   method, your code should look like the following:

```
public function afterAction($action, $result)
{
    $result = parent::afterAction($action, $result);
    // your custom code here
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: but if i want to run a method after my action call in backend how i can do that?

Comment: i mean the invoked action show my display page and i want to run a method  in background of my action !!!